# My WPF user control has one-way bindings and I don't know why

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have created a very simple user control that shows a `ColorPicker` (from the WPF Extended Toolkit) and a text field for its hex code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="HexColorPicker"> <!-- namespace declarations omitted -->
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <glue:ColorToRgbHex x:Key="colorToHex"/> <!-- custom converter I made -->
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="layoutRoot">
        <Label Content="#"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedColor, Converter={StaticResource colorToHex}}"/>
        <extToolkit:ColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding SelectedColor}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And here is the backing code:

```
public partial class HexColorPicker : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Color), typeof(HexColorPicker));

    public HexColorPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        layoutRoot.DataContext = this;
    }

    public Color SelectedColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

The `layoutRoot.DataContext` shenanigans come from [this place I found](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/).

I then use my control like that:

```
<me:HexColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding MyColor}"/>
```

And it somewhat works. The text field and the color picker are in sync: when one changes, the other changes as well. However, the control and the model object aren't two-way synced: my control will update if I change the model object's `MyColor` property, but the `MyColor` property will not update when I change it with my control.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the binding one-way from my model to my control only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your DependencyProperty Declaration to:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof (Color), typeof (HexColorPicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Color),FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Comment: I am somewhat surprised that the guys at Microsoft thought it shouldn't be two-ways by default.

Comment: @zneak There are lots of cases where `TwoWay` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I seriously can't think of any situation where a control would want to modify a property on itself but not sync it back to the model. I can imagine that having two-way bindings is not useful with properties that the control isn't going to change by itself, but precisely because of that, it wouldn't be harmful either.

Comment: @zneak I guess oneway bindings are more lightweight than twoways. And the % of properties that make sense oneway only is greater than its counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>As I recall, bindings that convert between types sometimes default to `OneWay` binding.</strike>

From the reference for BindingMode.Default (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx):

> Uses the default Mode value of the binding target. The default value varies for each dependency property. In general, user-editable control properties, such as those of text boxes and check boxes, default to two-way bindings, whereas most other properties default to one-way bindings. A programmatic way to determine whether a dependency property binds one-way or two-way by default is to get the property metadata of the property using GetMetadata and then check the Boolean value of the BindsTwoWayByDefault property.

It looks like the problem is that your control isn't seen as a 'user-editable' control.

The easiest solution is to specify `Mode=TwoWay` in your binding.

Comment: "The easiest solution is to specify Mode=TwoWay in your binding". That's wrong. If you want your dependency property to bind two-way *by default*, the only way to achieve that is to set the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` flag, as shown in the other answer.

Comment: Rethink the *by default* part.